# What is best practice to interaction with object in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

My questions is next:

For example I have object A (this is data model object). Assume that object A have some property (for example **request** property). Also I have object B (this is my view object).

So my problem is next: when my data model will be changed (the value for **request** property changed) I want to know about this events in my view (object B)

How to create this interaction between object.

For example in request  is written to "some_value" and after this object B immediately know about it.

Thanks for response!

Comment: For observing specific properties you want to use KVO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).  Your view controller (not the view itself) would set itself up as an observer for the data model object and when it gets observer notifications, it would update the view.

```
[myDataObject addObserver: myViewController 
               forKeyPath: @"request"  
                  options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context: nil];

// in the view controller you need

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString*) path
                      ofObject: (id) aDataObject
                        change: (NSDictionary*) changeDictionary
                       context: (void*) context]
{
    if (aDataObject == myDataObject
        && [path isEqualToString: @"request"])
    {
        // change you are interested in
    }
    // Call suoer implementation of this method if it implements it
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observer when you are done with it.

Also, be careful in a threaded environment.  Observations are notified on the same thread that the change happens on.  If this is not the main thread, you'll need to use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to make any changes to the UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegation pattern, NSNotifications, callback blocks and even KVO. Choice depends on situation, in your case delegate or callback block would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want object B to know whats up I would suggest using delegation.
If maybe later you want object C, D and E to know too what happend in object A i would suggest using NSNotification.

Answer (score 0):

For example I have class DataModel. In this step I add observer for my property **str**. For object I will send my view controller.

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *str;

- (void)setUpObserver:(id)object;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "DataModel.h"

@implementation DataModel

@synthesize str;

- (void)setUpObserver:(id)object
{ 
    [self addObserver:object forKeyPath: @"str" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: nil];
}

@end
```

In my view controller

```
#import "DataModel.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dm = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    [dm setUpObserver:self];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    if (object == dm && [keyPath isEqualToString: @"str"])
    {
        NSLog(@"it's work");
    }


}

- (IBAction)changeValue:(id)sender {
    dm.str = @"test change value";
}

@end
```

This is my realization of KVO. Thanks JeremyP for explanation.